# NumberFormatException parseInt Java

Tags: java, parseint, numberformatexception

I am trying to differentiate and store data (Point: x, y) from a text file in two arraylists: knots and zeros. Data File just contains integers or decimal values.

```
Data File:
x    y  type(zero/knot) 
46  10      2
13  5       2
27  21      1
```

But my code is throwing NumberFormatException:48

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class program {

    public static void main(String []args)  {
        ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();
        ArrayList zeros = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line = null;
        String file = "data1.txt";
        BufferedReader reader;
        try  {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(line);
                for (String s:tmp) {
                    s = s.replace("\r\n","");
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                    //knots.add(new Point();
                System.out.println(s);
              }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be due to your file header line?

Comment: so the line "x    y  type(zero/knot) " isn't actually in the file?

Comment: You are trying to foramt a string

Comment: Yeah,"x y type" is not in the file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file contents is EXACTLY...

```
46  10      2
13  5       2
27  21      1
```

When I run you code, I get the output...

```
46  10      2
46
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at testparser.TestParser.main(TestParser.java:47)
```

This would seem to indicate that there are blank/empty Strings in the output...

If I replace this section...

```
for (String s : tmp) {
    s = s.replace("\r\n", "");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
    //knots.add(new Point();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

With...

```
for (String s : tmp) {
    s = s.trim();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
        //knots.add(new Point();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I get...

```
46  10      2
46
10
2
13  5       2
13
5
2
27  21      1
27
21
1
```

Don't forget, `readline` will not return the line terminator, so you should be able to ignore it.

`line.split(" ")` is spliting on each "individual" space, meaning that if you have more than one space character together, then it will return the second space...;)

If, instead, you use `String tmp[] = line.split("\\s+");`, it will split on any spaces between all the other characters...not returning any "blank" `String`s (making the `if (s.length() > 0) {` check redundant)

Comment: @user2398101 Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your split line. It should be like this `String a[]=s.split(" +");`
What happened in your case is : When it split "46  10      2" string with `" "`, it counts only one space for spliting the String. So it ignores one space after `46` and `10` and then looks for the String. But there is no string after one space so it takes `""` as a string and try to parse it in integer. Though `""` can't be parsed into integer,it throws NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

You said you are parsing decimal numbers as well. Those cannot be parsed with `Integer.parseInt()`. You need to use `Double.parseDouble()` or `Float.parseFloat()` to parse decimal values from a String.

Also, it looks like you are trying to parse your header in your file. Make sure to do a token `readLine()` call before you begin the reading of the data, otherwise you'll try to parse text and that makes no sense and will crash.

Comment: Right now, I am just trying to do integer values, I have two separate data files.

Comment: Then the advice in my second paragraph likely applies, but it will be important to know about parsing floating point values for when you read the other file.

Comment: "x y type" is just for illustration, it is not there in the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.. It works fine for me

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class program 
{
    public static void main(String []args)  
    {
        ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();
        ArrayList zeros = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line = null;
        String file = "data1.txt";
        BufferedReader reader;
        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(line);
                for (String s:tmp) 
                {   
                    if(! (s.isEmpty()) )
                    {
                        int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)  
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.